# Configure OpenVpn on remote server

Tags: openvpn, bridge, dedicated-server

This is the scenario... I have a dedicated virtual server running on Centos7.
the sever is connected to the internet with a valid ip address (xx.xx.xx.xx) through bridged interface venet0:0

## ip addr

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
link/void
inet 127.0.0.1/32 scope host venet0
inet xx.xx.xx.xx/24 brd xx.xx.xx.yy scope global venet0:0
```

now I want to configure an openvpn server in bridged mode to let outside clients connect to the internet using my server's internet connection.

I've been able to run the server in tunnel mode successfully but for the bridged mode I don't know what to do...

All configurations that I've seen (like the one bellow) pretend that the server is not directly connected to the internet but in my case it is and there is no internal network for the server.

```
              +----------------------+
              | [  OpenVPN Server  ] |
          tap0|   dlp.server.world   |eth0
              |                      |
              +-----------+----------+
         192.168.0.30:1194|br0
                          |
               192.168.0.1|
                   +------+-----+
-------------------|   Router   |---------------------
                   +------+-----+
                          |x.x.x.x:1194
          +---------------+--------------+    Internet
          |                              |
----------+------------------------------+------------
          |     +------------------+     |
          | tap0|                  |eth0 |
          +-----+    VPN Client    +-----+
     192.168.0.x|                  |10.0.0.10
                +------------------+
```

so... I'm confused how to configure the server.
would something like this line work in my vpn server's configuration?

```
server-bridge xx.xx.xx.xx 255.255.255.255 192.168.0.150 192.168.0.199
```

or should I create a virtual internal network with net address 192.168.0.0/24?

Comment: Do not use a bridge if your server is directly connected to the internet. Read the Openvpn [Ethernet Bridging](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/ethernet-bridging.html)